# Get ASCII value of string in C# to calculate simple CRC

Tags: c#, asp.net, crc

I'm doing a simple control CRC to a project of mine, which sends data via serial port to an Arduino.

I'm trying to calculate the CRC of the message:
A0h 45h 11h 83h or 69d 17d 160d 131d

Turned to string, which gives the message to calculate: "Eá◄â"
By turning to ASCII returns the result:
69d 63d 63d 63d

Why did this happen?
Code is below

tks

```
public byte CalculateCRC(string data)
{
    data = "Eá◄â";
    byte[] characters = new byte[System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetByteCount(data)];
    characters = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);

    byte result = 0;
    foreach (byte character in characters )
        result = (byte)(result + character);
    result = (byte)(result + 1);
    return result;
}
```

Comment: ASCII characters cannot include accented characters!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> [Encoding.ASCII Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.ascii.aspx):
>
> ASCII characters are limited to the lowest 128 Unicode characters, from U+0000 to U+007F.

So don't turn the input `A0h 45h 11h 83h` or `69d 17d 160d 131d` into a string, but create a byte array out of it.

Answer (score 2):

It may well be that you want [the encoding  Latin1 aka ISO-8859-1 aka CP28591](https://stackoverflow.com/a/932265/13087).

This encoding will map all bytes with hex values in the range 0-255 to the Unicode character with the same hex value - convenient for roundtripping values to be sent to a serial port.