# How to extended CODE ASCII viewed in c# like a?

Tags: c#, .net

I have this code in **c#** :

```
private string code()
{
   return Encoding.ASCII.GetString(new byte[] { System.Convert.ToByte(152) });
}
```

but when I read this code ASCII, the result is ? with code more than 127 but its work for code ASCII less than 127

I use this script, but not work for all code ASCII :

```
var e = Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1");
var s = e.GetString(new byte[] { 189 });
```

Comment: Take a look at this it basically answers your question.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/932148/c-sharp-and-encoding-ascii-getstring

Comment: yes i view this page but with encodage "latin1", the result of code ascii 128 to 160 give always a ?

Comment: ok it work with encoding "Windows-1252"

Comment: I agree that this is a dupe. Not only does the referenced question provide a solution, there's an answer from Jon Skeet explaining the limits of ASCII (i.e. you simply _cannot_ use character values higher than 127 with ASCII...ASCII is by definition only inclusive of character values of 127 and below).